# Encrypt Adobe PDF On Client End

Tags: pdf, encryption, adobe

We're building an Adobe PDF form that will be downloaded from our website, filled out by clients, and then emailed back to us.  We need each PDF sent back to us from email to be encrypted.  And when we receive it on our end we need to use C# to read the decrypted PDF.  I know there's a way for the user to add a password within the UI of Adobe PDF.  Is there a way to add the password within the Adobe PDF code?

On the Adobe website the only options I can find are to use external tools or Adobe's cloud platform.

Comment: You want the user to email the PDF back to you encrypted?

Comment: Yes, each PDF has to have a different encryption key and we need to know that key when it comes back to us so we can decrypt it.

Comment: The best way to do this is to encrypt the file prior to distributing it but setting the permissions to allow for editing of the fields.

Comment: Would that prevent people from viewing the content of the document during the transmission of the document?  However, that would mean that all of the PDFs are encrypted the same way.